# Linux - Executing a command in a Softlink

Tags: linux, symlink

Working on a lab, one of the exercises asks me to create a softlink called simple, no problem. I don't understand this next part though. Can anyone give me a tip?

"There is a command called 'showtree' in the directory you just linked to.  Execute this command using the newly created 'simple' link."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think he simply meant using `./softlink/showtree` to execute the  command.